# how to add shell var to git bash and navigate to it in cmd?

Tags: python, bash, visual-studio-code, automation

I use git bash in vs code IDE. I have added this alias to .bashrc and it works.

```
alias k2="cd ../../../kafka"
```

But I want to be able to press "k2" and go to this dir from anywhere.
How to add shell or env variable?

Answer (score 0):

to automate going back to kafka home dir and launching its servers(zookeeper, kafka-server) do this:

```
cd ~
vim .bash_profile
```

in it add:

```
export k2="C:/kafka/" # or where kafka is located
```

Now k2 is env var i can use in other scripts.

back in project folder, create myshell.sh file and edit:

```
#!/bin/bash 
cd "$k2"
```

This will simply navigate to the folder of kafka - from anywhere.

To run just type

```
. myshell.sh
```

If i want to completely automate launching server, make myshell.sh this:

```
#!/bin/bash 
cd "$k2"
bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties # or whatever cmd you use
```

Now running myshell.sh will start the server right away

Answer (score -1):

I think you can write a simple bash script to do this, https://askubuntu.com/questions/223691/how-do-i-create-a-script-file-for-terminal-commands, Just write your commands in a bash script, make it executable and run it each time. This should work fine in VS Code.

Comment: You could write a Powershell or CMD script then, I guess something like that would work too.